# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Arqade's [4th moderator election](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: LessPop_MoreFizz] [image: fredley] [image: MOD3_NAME]

Congratulations, you three!

They'll be joining [our existing crew](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5651201064435712/0).

Comment: Congratulations to the new mods!

Comment: Finally, I can stop mistaking @LessPop_MoreFizz for a mod! =D Also, grats all!

Comment: [The porkchop is dead, long live the diamond!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_king_is_dead,_long_live_the_king!)

Comment: Gtz :) Well deserved!

Comment: Congratulations to the new mods :)

Comment: @Grace [one of the flairs](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/flair/3610.png) refuse to update with diamond (and new avatar) can you force a server cache refresh?

Comment: I am curious about this statistic: `1,240 visited the site during the election, 1,263 visited the election page` This is out of line with previous elections, where about half the visitors hit the election page, and is especially odd since more visited the election page than the site. Is this a typical thing that happens during site elections on other sites?

Comment: @Vaishali I went two for three, not terrible. I only expected one of my picks to win.

Comment: Congratulations! I hope the lag between Europa and Earth won't be an issue ;)

Answer (score 13):

Numbers numbers numbers! The traditional summary report is in Grace's answer, so here's some other numbers!

Voting distribution:

[image: Voting distribution]

ALL of the ballots: (Rows: first/second choice, columns; third choice)

> *Confusing table reading hints*:
>
> - 54 people voted LessPop first choice and fredley second.
> - 47 people gave LessPop first choice and fredley third.
> - 21 people cast a ballot with LessPop first, Strix second and fredley third.
> - 192 people gave LessPop first choice.
> - 64 people (all way at the bottom) gave LessPop third choice.
> - For the total of second choices, reference the graph above.

[image: enter link description here]

Just Strix vs Ashley, or *If You Liked Him You Shoulda Put First Choice On Him*:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Interesting to see how uncommon my ballot choice was.

Comment: @Vaishali I didn't actually show any visualization for the rounds.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh There is a lot of spread, yeah. I was the only one with my exact ballot. :)

Comment: This is where four dimensional graphs come in handy.

Comment: I don't understand any of it. :)

Comment: I feel like there could be more graphs here.